# Chrome Inspector: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: php, javascript, html

A php script is building the following (very complicated script that is too long to post here), but the chrome inspector is giving back "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". I'm having trouble finding the problem with the html below, any ideas?

```
<div id='580762bd48bb28c4ce3e1fafe5435969'>
    <div>There is 1 new comment on your <a href="/gci/user/aid1795">activity</a>.</div>
    <img src='/img/close.png' onclick='notificationViewed(3428, 2, 1795, 580762bd48bb28c4ce3e1fafe5435969)'></img>
</div>
</br></br>
<div id='afc89b3105b7a29d764dcebe75d2f5ef'>
    <div>There is 1 new comment on your <a href="/gci/user/aid3">activity</a>.</div>
    <img src='/img/close.png' onclick='notificationViewed(3428, 2, 3, afc89b3105b7a29d764dcebe75d2f5ef)'></img>
</div>
</br></br>
<div id='29f4b2518ab7498273466d4c584c6c2c'>
    <div>There are 2 new comments on your <a href="/gci/forecast/ifp.php?iid=269">comment</a>.</div>
    <img src='/img/close.png' onclick='notificationViewed(3428, 3, ifpgci269, 29f4b2518ab7498273466d4c584c6c2c)'></img>
</div>
</br></br>
<div id='5cbe38a820ff37f4522fc314e14b1fd6'>
    <div>There are 2 new comments on "<a href="/gci/forecast/ifp.php?iid=269">Test1</a>".</div>
    <img src='/img/close.png' onclick='notificationViewed(3428, 1, ifpgci269, 5cbe38a820ff37f4522fc314e14b1fd6)'></img>
</div>
</br></br>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is horribly invalid.  Get rid of the closing </img> tags and the </br> tags.  These, while valid XML, are not used in HTML.  Because your HTML is so atrocious I refuse to examine it further.

Comment: True you don't need to close image tags for HTML, but you do for XHTML.

Comment: The closing </img> tag will not be accepted by IE.  Instead make image tags a singleton such that there is a forward slash directly before the closing delimiter:  <img src="" alt=""/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the strings in your event function calls:

```
 onclick='notificationViewed(3428, 1, "ifpgci269", "5cbe38a820ff37f4522fc314e14b1fd6")'
```

Comment: That was it, cant believe i missed that. Thanks! I'll give it to you since you posted first :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
onclick='notificationViewed(3428, 2, 1795, **580762bd48bb28c4ce3e1fafe5435969**)'
```

You wither want quote marks round that hex to make it a string, or `0x` before it to signify that it is hex.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer for anyone stumbling upon this question...

This particular error is not specified by Chrome, but debugging in Firefox (using Firebug) will give you more info.